# Android SensorManager.getOrientation() returns pitch between -PI/2 and PI/2

Tags: android, android-sensors, angle, device-orientation, motion-detection

I am designing an app that needs to check the device's orientation (Azimuth, Pitch and Roll). I use the following code to achieve this:

```java
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        gravityMatrix = event.values.clone();// Fill gravityMatrix with accelerometer values
    else if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        geomagneticMatrix = event.values.clone();// Fill geomagneticMatrix with magnetic-field sensor values
    if(gravityMatrix != null && geomagneticMatrix != null){
        RMatrix = new float[16];
        IMatrix = new float[16];

        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(RMatrix, IMatrix, gravityMatrix, geomagneticMatrix);// Retrieve RMatrix, necessary for the getOrientation method
        SensorManager.getOrientation(RMatrix, orientation);// Get the current orientation of the device
    }
}
```

Now I am able to get azimuth, pitch and roll values from the 'orientation' float[]. Everything goes fine for the azimuth and roll values (it returns the correct angle), however when I print the pitch value (orientation[1]), I always retrieve an angle between PI/2 and -PI/2. I don't understand why? I am unable to retrieve an angle greater than PI/2 or less than -PI/2. As soon as I have an angle of +- PI/2 and I keep on rotating my device (Samsung Galaxy S2) the angle suddenly decreases after it reached the PI/2 value.

Can anyone explain me why the pitch-angle is behaving so uncommon?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Pitch is calculated as `pitch = (float) Math.asin(-RMatrix[7]);` The range of the `arcsin` function is `[-PI/2, PI/2]`, so `asin` can only take value in between `-PI/2` and `PI/2`.

Comment: Oke, thank you very much. That really makes sense, I didn't know that. However I have to know the difference between these 2 orientations that have the same pitch, so I think I'm going to use the azimuth value. It changes from negative to positive when the device keeps rotating over the X-axis. I'll let you know if that works.

Comment: I found the solution! It's very simple actually:
    'if(gravityMatrix[2]<0)
    orientation[1] = (float) (Math.PI - orientation[1]);'
It works because the gravity on the z-axis changes from positive to negative when the device keeps rotating over its X-axis.
So this returns the correct pitch (values between 0 and PI, 0 and -PI)
Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: on my Sony Xperia Z5P, for the pitch, I was seeing a range of values from -0 (flat on table) to -90 (standing up) and back to -0 (face-down on table) so I had no way of knowing what was up and down ! With that fix I can finally have the app decide whether the user is looking up or down. Hopefully this is not hardware specific !