# Android getOrientation issue - mirrored values along axis

Tags: java, android, orientation

I've got some troubles with getOrientation. I'm running my application in landscape mode and I have troubles with one axis. There's more explanation in code, some images:

[image]
[image]

```
    valuesMagnet      = new float[3];
    valuesAccel       = new float[3];
    valuesOrientation = new float[3];
    rotationMatrix    = new float[9];
    rotationMatrixTemp= new float[9];

....


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, valuesAccel, 0, 3);
            break;

        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, valuesMagnet, 0, 3);
            break;
    }

    if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrixTemp, null, valuesAccel, valuesMagnet)) {
        //SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrixTemp, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, rotationMatrix);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, valuesOrientation);

        for (int i = 0; i < valuesOrientation.length; i++) {
            valuesOrientation[i] /= Math.PI;
            valuesOrientation[i] *= 100;
            valuesOrientation[i] = (int)valuesOrientation[i];
            valuesOrientation[i] /= 100;
        }

        updateOrientationBuffer(valuesOrientation);

        quadcopter.onEvent(new Event(Event.Codes.ORIENTATION_CHANGED, calculateSmoothedOrientation()));
    }
    else {
        Log.d("App", "Matrix rotate error");
    }
}
```

I want `orientation[1]` axis to give full spectrum of values between -1 and 1 while rotating phone by 180 degrees. Also, target device as no gyroscope.

Comment: can you post more of your code to see how you're generating valuesAccel and valuesMagnet?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/hardware/SensorEvent.java
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/hardware/SensorListener.java?av=f

Comment: Do you use `SensorManager` to obtain the orientation sensor? Or do you use raw sensor data? I am not sure (I found different info in docs) but I think the first one may be using *radians* and the second - *degrees*. Check please if it's not the case.

Comment: @barn.gumbl: Sorry, but at this moment I don't know how should I use this.

Comment: @alex: I'm using sensorManager to register accelerometer & magnetic field sensor. As documentation says, it's necessary to calculate orientation using getRotationMatrix and getOrientation

Comment: Well, I'd just check min and max values you get. You'd know the unit for sure. And then you could rescale it to <-1;1>

Comment: @alex orientation[2] values are between -PI and +PI. orientation[1] values are between -PI/2 and PI/2. To be more exact, orientation[1] values are: 0 (camera facing ground)  -->  PI/2   -->  0 (camera facing sky)  -->   -PI/2  --> 0   (camera facing ground again)

Comment: It's hard to understand what your pictures mean. I noticed "qaudcopter" in your code. I suppose you want to control it with phone, when phone is laying then quadcopter is not moving, when phone is tilted left then quadcopter moves to it's left. To do it you need only x,y axises from accelerometer. You rather don't want to know if your phone faces to the north or east - this is what you get with orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, valuesAccel, 0, 3);
            break;

        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, valuesMagnet, 0, 3);
            break;

        case Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY:
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, valuesGravity, 0, 3);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrixTemp, null, valuesAccel, valuesMagnet)) {
        SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrixTemp, valuesOrientation);

        if(valuesGravity[2] < 0)                                     {
            if (valuesOrientation[1] > 0) {
                valuesOrientation[1] = (float) (Math.PI - valuesOrientation[1]);
            }
            else {
                valuesOrientation[1] = (float) (-Math.PI - valuesOrientation[1]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < valuesOrientation.length; i++) {
            valuesOrientation[i] /= Math.PI;
            valuesOrientation[i] *= 100;
            valuesOrientation[i] = (int)valuesOrientation[i];
            valuesOrientation[i] /= 100;
        }


        updateOrientationBuffer(valuesOrientation);

        quadcopter.onEvent(new Event(Event.Codes.ORIENTATION_CHANGED, calculateSmoothedOrientation()));
    }
    else {
        Log.d("Quadcopter-SM", "Matrix rotate error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the problem you are facing what I understood is you are focusing on mainly two axes and that are mainly X and Y according to Cartesian system.

Here in the Ans I will refere Orintation1 as X and Orientation2 as Y.

So you want the spectrum of values when rotation happens on X axes between -90 to 90 degree.

I have analyzed the problem and your code and below is my solution for the problem is stated.

```
package com.example.stackoverflowquestion;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor accel, magnet;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accel = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnet = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (accel != null) {
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accel,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Accelerometer not available",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (magnet != null) {
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnet,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "MagnetoMeter not available",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    float[] accelMat = new float[3];
    float[] magMat = new float[3];
    float[] rotmat = new float[9];
    float[] orientationMat = new float[3];

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, accelMat, 0, 3);
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, magMat, 0, 3);
            break;
        }

        if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotmat, null, accelMat, magMat)) {
            SensorManager.getOrientation(rotmat, orientationMat);

            for (int i = 0; i < orientationMat.length; i++) {
                // convert from redians to degrees
                orientationMat[i] = (float) (orientationMat[i] / Math.PI) * 180;
            }
            Log.d("yaw", ":" + orientationMat[0]);
            Log.d("pitch", ":" + orientationMat[1]);
            Log.d("roll", ":" + orientationMat[2]);

        }

    }
}
```

This code prints the logs in the degrees and if you want in redians then simple formula change is required.

Note : This code will also work in the device which is not having gyroscope. I have tested on HTC Evo 4G device and got the results as expected.

Comment: Sorry, but pitch in your solution is between -90 and 90, not -180 and 180 as it is in roll. Still, eg. -45 deg would mean two different pitch rotations.
And I think I've found solution in comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747823/android-sensormanager-getorientation-returns-pitch-between-pi-2-and-pi-2
I'm testing it.

Comment: ok.that's good you have found the solution, but the formula which we have used will be useful.

Comment: Also, in this case, solution up wasn't full enough, I'm waiting for my friend to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [getOrientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getOrientation(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D)) claims that it returns a pitch between -π to π. This can't be true since the implementation is `values[1] = (float) Math.asin(-R[7]);` (`asin` returns values between -π/2 and π/2)

This is a [known issue](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37127944) that Google won't fix. I created my own `getOrientation` function based on [Gregory G. Slabaugh's paper](http://%20http://www.close-range.com/docs/Computing_Euler_angles_from_a_rotation_matrix.pdf)

```
// Based on pseudo code from http://www.close-range.com/docs/Computing_Euler_angles_from_a_rotation_matrix.pdf
object EulerAngleHelper {
    private const val R11 = 0
    private const val R12 = 1
    private const val R13 = 2
    private const val R21 = 3
    private const val R22 = 4
    private const val R23 = 5
    private const val R31 = 6
    private const val R32 = 7
    private const val R33 = 8
    private const val AZIMUTH = 0
    private const val PITCH = 1
    private const val ROLL = 2
    private const val PHI_Z = AZIMUTH
    private const val PSI_X = PITCH
    private const val THETA_Y = ROLL

    fun getOrientation(r: DoubleArray, values: DoubleArray): DoubleArray {
        when {
            r[R31] < -0.98 -> {
                values[PHI_Z] = 0.0 // Anything; can set to 0
                values[THETA_Y] = Math.PI / 2
                values[PSI_X] = values[PHI_Z] + atan2(r[R12], r[R13])
            }
            r[R31] > 0.98 -> {
                values[PHI_Z] = 0.0 // Anything; can set to 0
                values[THETA_Y] = -Math.PI / 2
                values[PSI_X] = values[PHI_Z] + atan2(-r[R12], -r[R13])
            }
            else -> {
                values[THETA_Y] = -asin(r[R31])
                val cosTheta = cos(values[THETA_Y])
                values[PSI_X] = atan2(r[R32] / cosTheta, r[R33] / cosTheta)
                values[PHI_Z] = atan2(r[R21] / cosTheta, r[R11] / cosTheta)
            }
        }
        return values
    }
}
```

I've only tested the pitch and roll.